# Why does Julia Int64, Float64 and boolean support getindex

Tags: julia

In Julia, you can declare an `Int64`, `Bool` or a `Float64` and index it with `1`.

```
julia>  aa = 10
10

julia> typeof(10)
Int64

julia> aa[1]
10

julia> aa[0]
ERROR: BoundsError
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Int64, ::Int64) at .\number.jl:78
 [2] top-level scope at none:0

julia> aa[2]
ERROR: BoundsError
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Int64, ::Int64) at .\number.jl:78
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

Are there practical or theoretical reasons for this functionality to exist? I have never seen it in any other language I've used (Python, Ruby, Matlab, C++).

Comment: Actually, you would see exactly the same thing in Matlab. A scalar is just a 1x1 matrix in Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is twofold:

1. Numbers are treated by Julia as `0`-dimensional containers.
2. If you add `1` as a dimension index number in `getindex` then it is not an error, even if `1` is beyond the dimensionality of the container.

These two rules in combination lead to the behavior you describe. Here are some more examples of the same:

```
julia> a = 1
1

julia> b = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a[]
1

julia> a[1,1,1,1]
1

julia> b[2,1,1,1,1]
2
```

and note that standard functions defined for containers are defined for numbers and behave as for `0`-dimensional objects, e.g.:

```
julia> size(a)
()

julia> axes(a)
()
```

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/30736/files) that gives more details how omitted and extra indices work.